# Image inside AbsoluteLayout taking too much extra space

Tags: xamarin.forms

The design requirement is to put a `label` and a `button` on the `image`. The Image is in a `DataTemplate` of `ListView`. I want to use `Absolute Layout`. But the `image` and `AbsoluteLayout` is taking too much space. So how to make the `AbsoluteLayout` and `image` to the `mimimum` size. I know `Absolute Layout` is the best for this scenario. But it is leaving lots of empty space between list view `items`. Please help me out and explain how to create Layout appropriately in order to size them to the minimum. The code is as follows

```
 <ListView HasUnevenRows="true"  SeparatorVisibility="None">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <ViewCell>

                         <AbsoluteLayout >

                            <Image Source="BuyersCard.png" > </Image>

                           <Label Text="{Binding Name}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".1,.2"></Label>

                                <Button Text="Contact" BorderColor="Red" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".7,.2"></Button>

                        </AbsoluteLayout>
                      </ViewCell>       
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>

        </ListView>
```

**EDIT**

[image]

The top item is selected. See the gap between each item. The whole gray area is selected when i tap on the listview item. I want just the space of 10pixel in between each item

Comment: `<AbsoluteLayout HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Azure">
            <Image x:Name="cameraImage" BackgroundColor="Accent" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 0, 200,100" />
            <Label Text="Stylish Header" FontSize="25"
           AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0, 25, AutoSize, AutoSize"/>
            <Button Text="Button" BackgroundColor="DarkViolet" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,70,100,30"/>
    </AbsoluteLayout>` Have a try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually decided to look at the `.png` files themselves and discovered that they have many `transparent pixels` around! This is causing the image to render with the apparent `margins` on the `top/bottom` and sides. See the below screenshot:

[image]

The `AbsoluteLayout` have Red Background and Image have `Aqua` Background.After `cropping` the image of these `pixels`, the space is significantly reduced. However `AbsoluteLayout` is still for some reason causing `extra` space at the `bottom`. I set the `HeightRequest` of the `AbsoluteLayout` to `150`. Thus the extra space around the image taken by AbsoluteLayout is gone. Now I have this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well the absolute layout can be tricky sometimes and this kind of trickery is sort of my thing:

Now how I would do it is something like below:

```
 <ListView HasUnevenRows="true"  SeparatorVisibility="None">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
              <ViewCell>
               <AbsoluteLayout> 
               <StackLayout Spacing="0" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All", AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"> 
    <Image Source="BuyersCard.png" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" 
           VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Aspect="AspectFill"/>
               </StackLayout>     
        <Label Text="{Binding Name}" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".1,.2"/>
        <Button Text="Contact" BorderColor="Red" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".7,.2"/>       
              </AbsoluteLayout>
             </ViewCell>          
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: This does not work. All I want is to shrink the AbsosuteLayout to the size of the image. What you are trying is to expand the image to the size of the AbsoluteLayout.

Comment: Umm okay i can do that, your question did not mention this

Comment: If you can do this please correct your answer accordingly. Thanks

Comment: Done take a look and let me know if it worked for you!

Comment: The label and button remain above the image. Test your answer before posting

Comment: So you don't want that? Because your needs are something else and your question has nothing about that! Isn't that what you wanted `label and a button on the image`

Comment: I have tested it now and updated my answer, you can check same!

Comment: And just so you know you will have to change the button and Label's LayoutFlags and LayoutBounds as per your requirement,

Comment: Still not working When I select a  list view item the selected space is about double than the image. Whereas I want the listview item to be the size of the image.